# My question is about "considering a bean into the configuration class"

Tags: java, spring

Description:

> Field entryPoint in security.demo.config.SecurityConfig required a bean of type 'security.demo.config.jwt.JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint' that could not be found.

Action:

> Consider defining a bean of type 'security.demo.config.jwt.JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint' in your configuration.

How can I fix this error if I have these configuration class?

---

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthProvider autheticationProvider;
    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint;

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
        return new ProviderManager(Collections.singletonList(autheticationProvider));
    }

    //create a custom filter
    @Bean
    public JwtAuthFilter authTokenFilter() {
        JwtAuthFilter filter =new JwtAuthFilter();
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(new JwtSuccessHandler());
        return filter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
                .usersByUsernameQuery("select email as principal, password as credentials, true from users where email=?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select user_email as principal, role_name as role from user_roles where user_email=?")
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder()).rolePrefix("ROLE_");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/register**", "/forgot-password**", "/reset-password**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/register**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/users", "/addTask")
                .hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/profile")
                .and()
                .logout()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .and().rememberMe().key("unique-and-secret").rememberMeCookieName("remember-me-cookie-name").tokenValiditySeconds(24 * 60 * 60);
        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint);
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http.addFilterBefore(authTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

And the JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint class is:

```
    public class JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1, AuthenticationException arg2)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        arg1.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,"UNAUTHARIZED");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `@Component` over `JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint` class